# how to get all href links from web url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, html

I want to get all href links from a web url(url:http://localhost/test.php) including file also because i have included one php file (menulink.php)
my script is working only for outside of href and if condition checked href only.

```
<a href="test.html" title="test"></a>
<a href="test1.html" title="test1"></a>
<a href="menulink1.html" title="menulink1"></a>
<a href="menulink2.html" title="menulink2"></a>
```

if condition true:

```
 <a href="test4.html" title="test4"></a>
 <a href="menulink3.html" title="menulink3"></a>
```

but i want to get else condition also both time(i need all href links do not consider if else condition or whatever condition)

Missing href links:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" title="test6"></a>
<a href="menulink5.html" title="menulink5"></a>
<a href="menulink6.html" title="menulink6"></a>
```

how can i do it?can you resolve from my code.
This is my code:

index.html

```
         $(document).ready(function(){

        var url = "http://localhost/links/test.php"; 
        var arr= null;
         $.post('load.php', { url: url,async: false},
            function(html) {
                $('#page').html(html);  
                var links = $('a');
                var title = $('a').attr('title');  

                var arr=[];
                for(var i=0; i < links.length; i++)
                {
                    arr.push(links[i]); 
                }
                console.log(arr); //all href links//  
        }  );

    });
```

test.php

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div>
  <?php include("menulink.php"); ?>

   <a href="test.html" title="test"></a>
   <a href="test1.html" title="test1"></a>
   <?php
   $result_array="123";
   if ($result_array=="123")
   {
   ?>
   <a href="test4.html" title="test4"></a>
   <?php 
   }
   else{
   ?>
   <a href="http://www.google.com" title="test6"></a>
   <?php
   } 
   ?>
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

load.php

```
<?php
$url = $_POST['url'];
$html = file_get_contents($url);
echo $html;
?>
```

menulink.php

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div>
  <a href="menulink1.html" title="menulink1"></a>
  <a href="menulink2.html" title="menulink2"></a> 
  <?php
  $result_array="123";
  if ($result_array=="123")
  {
  ?>
  <a href="menulink3.html" title="menulink3"></a>

  <?php 
  }
  else{
  ?>
  <a href="menulink5.html" title="menulink5"></a>
  <a href="menulink6.html" title="menulink6"></a>
  <?php
  }
  ?>

 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

i want to get all the href links. Do not consider if else conditions or whatever conditions from the url document.please resolve from my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
     $dom = new DOMDocument;
     $dom->validateOnParse = true;
     $dom->loadHTML($html);
     $links = array(); 
     foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a'); as $link) { 
        $links[] = $link->getAttribute('href'); 
     }
```

Comment: In your load.php
Sorry i forgot to add it

Comment: Can you var_dump($links); ?

Comment: not working..please edit load.php and send full code

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create DOM from URL or file //you have to include simple_html_dom.php form above link

$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');



// Find all links
```

You have to do this in load.php file as

```
         include("simple_html_dom.php");  // please make sure right location of file 
$url = $_POST['url'];
$html = file_get_html($url);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$links = array(); 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
    $links[] = $element->href;
    } echo json_encode($links);
```

and in jquery get those links

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        var url = "http://localhost/links/test.php"; 
        //var arr= null;
         $.post('load.php', { url: url,async: false},
            function(html) {
                $('#page').html(html);  
                console.log(html);
        }  );

    });

HTML

        <html>
      <head>
      <title>Test</title>
      </head>
      <body>
      <div>


      <?php include("menulink.php"); ?>

       <a href="test.html" title="test"></a>
       <a href="test1.html" title="test1"></a>
       <?php
       get_links("123");
       get_links("321");
        function get_links($a){
            ?>
            <?php
       $result_array=$a;
       if ($result_array=="123")
       {
       ?>
       <a href="test4.html" title="test4"></a>
       <?php 
       }
       else{
       ?>
       <a href="http://www.google.com" title="test6"></a>
       <?php
       } 
       ?>
            <?php
        }
}
       ?>
       </div>
       </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: please read my question. your script is not working..getting error:Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function file_get_html()

Comment: You have to download it

Comment: i have added but not working..i am not getting all href links

Comment: load.php file only. let me see what you have done in that

Comment: <?php
include("simple_html_dom.php");
$url = $_POST['url'];
 
     $html = file_get_html($url);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $links = array();
    foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {

           $links[] = $element->href;
     }

echo json_encode($links);
?>

Comment: I have just tested it .local server seems fine.can you show me the console.log();
and if php file giving blank page white page
use
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
in start to show errors

Comment: i am getting in console.log: Array [ "menulink1.html", "menulink2.html", "menulink3.html", "menulink4.html", "test.html", "test1.html", "test4.html", "test5.html", "http://www.si.com" ]. missing other links(else condition links) i want to get all href links.

Comment: You have to remove else condition  in test .php   in order to get those link
because html page itself not rendering ..cause its not on page

Comment: PHP out put only HTML and if html is not there.No one can fetch all links

Comment: i want all links..is it possible or not?

Comment: please do not remove else condition..need esle condition

Comment: Check again.. this is the final html version. Otherwise impossible to get solution

Comment: do not add any thing in test.php file.  can u remove  php open and close tag(<?php...?>) and other condition before file_get_html

Comment: Than  legally no solution for this

Comment: cau u take clone test.php as a text file and then check all the urls rite?